# Monitoring headless Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-headless, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm using Chrome in headless mode via CDP (Chrome devtools protocol) to do HTML to PDF conversions. Works well but I do not trust Chrome to run forever and want to build a guardian service to monitor its responsiveness and if necessary kill the process and relaunch it.

What would be a good indicator of health? What I'm looking for is a low overhead test I can perform at fairly frequent intervals so that the restart latency is minimised.

- I could try to perform some kind of CDP command if anyone has a suggestion and a reliable way to determine success.
- I can't think of anything else, that's why I've thrown it open for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

My best suggestion for this case is to use the [Target domain](https://vanilla.aslushnikov.com/?Target). Listening to some of the events that are fired from the target domain will give you some information regarding the state of your browser, such as **TargetCrashed**.

On top of that, you could use basic domains like **Runtime** (provides the *evaluate* method), **SystemInfo** or **Browser** to send the browser requests in order to check its health.